systemd DVB frontend device targets not created
Since I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS to Ubuntu 24.10, with new motherboard,cpu,nvme, using both kernel 6.11.7, the systemd DVB frontend device targets are not created.
Besides this, everything works on the new system. The systemd unit files have been used since many years.
Unfortunately, I cannot check with old Linux installation, as it complains about "hd0,gpt2" and not finding root device at boot.
What is causing the systemd DVB frontend devices targets not to be created, and therefor the awaits to fail?
systemd-analyze plot >plot.svg, does also not show the targets, however an old plot.svg shows them.
Following are the journal snippets from the new and the old system, and the systemd package used:
newsys# journalctl --file=/var/log/journal/*/system.journal | grep frontend

Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter0-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter0-frontend0.device/start timed out.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-dvb-adapter0-frontend0.device - /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter0-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter0-frontend0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter2-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter2-frontend0.device/start timed out.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-dvb-adapter2-frontend0.device - /dev/dvb/adapter2/frontend0.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter2-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter2-frontend0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter3-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter3-frontend0.device/start timed out.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-dvb-adapter3-frontend0.device - /dev/dvb/adapter3/frontend0.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter3-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter3-frontend0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter1-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter1-frontend0.device/start timed out.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-dvb-adapter1-frontend0.device - /dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0.
Nov 18 16:35:17 newsys systemd[1]: dev-dvb-adapter1-frontend0.device: Job dev-dvb-adapter1-frontend0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.

ii  systemd                                 256.5-2ubuntu3                             amd64        system and service manager


oldsys# journalctl --file=/var/log/journal/*/system.journal | grep frontend

Nov 10 10:46:32 oldsys systemd[1]: Found device /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0.
Nov 10 10:46:32 oldsys systemd[1]: Found device /dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0.
Nov 10 10:46:32 oldsys systemd[1]: Found device /dev/dvb/adapter2/frontend0.
Nov 10 10:46:32 oldsys systemd[1]: Found device /dev/dvb/adapter3/frontend0.

ii  systemd                               249.11-0ubuntu3.12                           amd64        system and service manager


Add a udev rule:
SUBSYSTEM=="dvb", TAG+="systemd"
It triggers systemd services, when devices in the dvb subsystem are added or removed
